# Can I wrap by word but consider sometimes 3 words as one? In NSLineBreakMode .byWordWrapping

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Sometimes I have a sentence like this inside a multiple line cell that uses byWordWrapping:

*"Some random comment. 1 minute ago."*

But sometimes that is truncated to 2 different lines, and I see:

*"Some random comment. 1"*

*"minute ago."*

That's not very nice. I would prefer this or even 3 lines in the worst case:

*"Some random comment."
"1 minute ago."*

Is there any way to declare "1 minute ago" as one word?
My first idea was to add a dummy character in the middle and use the same colour than the background. But well, that is a workaround and that string is generated by a date formatter and could be very different in another language, so I guess it could fail sometimes.

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: How about adding a return before the date? Then it will always be on the last line.  Or make two labels, one for the comment, and one for the date.

Comment: @Koen Adding a return would be a workaround, not a solution. e.g. if the comment is only one word like "Good! 1 min ago", he doesn't want 2 lines for that.
Regarding making 2 labels: if doesn't change anything, the second label would still be wrapped at word boundaries (default behavior).

Comment: Ok, just throwing out thoughts here. How about adding an NSParagraphStyle attribute where you turn off the word wrapping (I don't even know if that is even possible)?